# What is the Galois group of narrow Hilbert class field over Hilbert class field?

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, class-field-theory

I am trying to solve the following question:

Let $K$ be a number field, $H'$ and $H$ be the narrow Hilbert class field and Hilbert class field respectively. Let $O^*_{K,+}\subset O^*_{K}$ be the group of totally positive units. Show that $Gal(H'/H)\cong (Z/2Z)^{r-t}$ where $r$ is the set of real places and $2^t=[ O^*_{K}:O^*_{K,+}]$.

Here is my effort: By the main theorem of CFT, we know that $Gal(H'/H)$ is exactly the kernel of the canonical surjective morphism $f: Cl(K, O_K)\to Cl(K)$, in order to compute the kernel, I use the Proposition 6.114 of Kazuya Kato's book, which is as follows:

> **PROPOSITION 6.114.** There exists a unique isomorphism
> $$\mathrm{Ker}(Cl(K,a)\to Cl(K))\cong \left(\left(\underset{v:\text{ real place}}{⊕}\Bbb R^\times/\Bbb R^\times_{>0}\right) ⊕ (O_K/a)^\times\right)/(\text{image of } O^\times_k)$$
> such that for a nonzero element of $b$ of $O_k$ relatively prime to $a$, $[(b)]\in\mathrm{Ker}(Cl(K),a)\to Cl(K))$ is sent to the image of $b$ on the right-hand side.

Since $R^*/R^*_{>0}\cong Z/2Z$, we just need to compute how many real place $\sigma$ of $K$ such that $[O^*_{\sigma{(K)}}:O^*_{\sigma{(K)},+}]=2$, we denote the number as $d$, then we need to show $d=t$. But I have no idea how to show it.

PS. My text book about CFT is Kazuya Kato's book, he define it without modulus, so I hope we can discuss it without using the concept of modulus.

Answer (score 2):

$\require{AMScd}$
Kato's $Cl(K,O_K)$ is usually denoted by $Cl^+(K)$. These groups are defined by the following diagrams, where $I_K$ is the group of fractional ideals, $P_K$ that of principal ideals, and $P_K^+$ that of totally positive ideals:
\begin{CD}
1 @>>> P_K^+ @>>> I_K  @>>> Cl^+(K)  @>>>  1 \\
 @.   @VVV   @VVV   @VVV @. \\
1 @>>> P_K^ @>>> I_K  @>>> Cl(K)  @>>>  1
\end{CD}
By the snake lemma, the group you're interested in is isomorphic to $P_K/P_K^+$.

The commutative diagram
\begin{CD}
1 @>>> O_{K,+}^* @>>> K^\times_+   @>>> P_K^+   @>>>  1 \\
 @.   @VVV   @VVV   @VVV @. \\
1 @>>> O_K^* @>>> K^\times   @>>> P_K   @>>>  1
\end{CD}
now answers your question since the quotient in the middle is
$K^\times/K^{\times}_+ \simeq ({\mathbb Z}/2{\mathbb Z})^r$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I realized that we don,t need to compute the number $d$, actually we just need to compute the kernel of $f: O_K* \to \oplus R^*/R^*_{>0}$, this kernel is exactly the group $O^*_{K, +}$, and after quotient the kernel, we get the injective group homomorphism, which is our image